# Can't find the attribute I'm looking for using Python ElementTree

Tags: python, elementtree

[image]I have an xml look like this:

`<fiscalYear start="2012-01-01" end="2012-12-31">2012`

`<startingBalance account="1220" balance="3453871"/>`
see picture for more info

Now I want to find if ex an account "1220" has a startingBalance for fiscalYear 2012. The problem is that I have several fiscalYears in the xml and in the attribute 
"startingBalance" I have no year to look for. So in some way I have to look both in "fiscalYear" and "startingBalance", but I don't know how to do it using ElementTree.

I have tried do like this:

```
fiscalYear = xmltree.iter('fiscalYear')
   startingBalance = 0
   for i in fiscalYear:
          if "startingBalance" in i.attrib:
                 print("found something")
                 if i.attrib['account'] == accountNr:
                        startingBalance = i.attrib['balance']
                 else:
                        print("No startingBalance found for account:", accountNr,"year:",year )
          else:
                 print("No startingBalance found for year:",year )
```

but it's just print out "No startingBalance found for year" 5times (5 fiscalyears in xml)

Do someone have a clue how to fix it...?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your xml right, then startingBalance is not an attrib, but a tag.  Change your if statement to

```
if "startingBalance" in i.tag:
```

and see if that doesn't help.

I tested you code with some xml I had here, and another problem is that your code is not getting to the subelements of fiscalYear.  You have to add another line that iterates through the subelements. Something like this:

```
   for i in fiscalYear:
       for subele in i:   
           if "startingBalance" in subele.tag:
               print("found something")
               if subele.attrib['account'] == accountNr:
                    startingBalance = subele.attrib['balance']
                    #etc, etc
```

Comment: Thx for helping, that didn't help, still the same output, any more ideas :)?

Comment: Check the type of the variable accountNr. It must be a string. If it's a number, then you won't get any matches.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick :)! Now I can find my startingBalance for a specific year! Thank you very much, it helps me alot!!

Comment: Glad it helped you. If you want to get rid of the nested iterators, just use xmlTree.getiterator(). That will recursively work through everything in the tree. And it's easier on your memory if you have a big xml.

Comment: Thx! It would be great to get rid of some nested iterators, I will try it out.

Comment: It was problem to use getiterator in version 3.2.2, maybe because of this: getiterator(tag=None)
Deprecated since version 2.7: Use method Element.iter() instead

Comment: I've been using getiterator for a while, but you are right, it's deprecated. I have to get with the program. I see in the docs that iter works the same if you don't pass an arg, same as getiterator.

Comment: source http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html
Regards/Martin